# Supee 8788 v2 is not showing patched magento1.9.2.2

Tags: php, security, magento, patch, issue-tracking

My Magento store version is 1.9.2.2 and recently I applied the
Magento 1.9.2.2-1.9.2.1 SUPEE-8788v2-1.9.2.1 from https://magentary.com/kb/install-supee-8788-without-ssh/. I have merged all the files on the root of my Magento store but it is still showing not patched.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

If you have applied the Patch but it is not showing in Magereport. Please take the below steps:

1. Blow static assets should be removed:

   ```
   skin/adminhtml/default/default/media/flex.swf
   skin/adminhtml/default/default/media/uploader.swf
   skin/adminhtml/default/default/media/uploaderSingle.swf
   ```
2. Below files should be updated with latest one. You can check by find the below words:

   ```
   js/mage/adminhtml/uploader/instance.js should contain "fustyFlowFactory"
   skin/adminhtml/default/default/boxes.css should contain "background:url(images/blank.gif) repeat;"
   ```

If above files are not updated, you can update with latest one.

Comment: yes i have checked this and its as suggested but still it is not showing patched.Is there any other thing you can suggest .

Comment: If there is any cache enable on server please clear that as well. After clear cache it worked for me.